# Persistence OneToMany list not being updated on persist

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence

I have a `Categories` and `Posts` entities and tables. I'm persisting a new Post which is successfully being added to the database however it seems the objects are not being added to the Categories List that is loaded.

Categories:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="categories")
public List<Post> getPosts() 
{
    return this.posts;
}
```

To add the new post to the database I'm simply doing:

```
Post newPost = new Post(..);
entityManager.persist(newPost);
```

So the new post gets added to the database however it seems the list of Posts that Categories has, isn't being updated until I restart the server or wait a few minutes.. This is how I fetch categories:

```
Category category = entityManager.find(Category.class, id);
```

And then I get the list of Posts from `getPosts()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information provided you have a uni-directional relationship:

```
Category --> * Post
```

For this scenario to work correctly, you would need access to the Category when creating and persisting the Post:

```
Category category = ...;
Post newPost = new Post(..);
category.getPosts().add(newPost);
entityManager.persist(newPost);
category = entityManager.merge(category);   // may not be needed if category is already managed
```

If it is a bidirectional relationship then you would also need:

```
newPost.setCategory(category);
```

prior to the `persist(newPost)`.